# Uniform continuity of composition?

Tags: analysis

If we consider $f\circ u$ and know that

- f is bounded and uniformly continuous
- u is bounded and continuous

does this imply that $f\circ u$ is bounded and uniformly continuous?

It is clear that it is bounded.

But it is not clear to me whether it is uniformly continuous. Surely it is continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no. You can give the following counter-example. Let your domain be $(0,1)$, $f(x)= x$ and $g(x)= x^2$. Then $f(g(x))= f(x^2)= x^2$ which is bounded, continuous, but not uniformly continuous on the given domain.

Comment: What if $u\in C([0,T]\times\mathbb{R})$ where $T>0$? Does this make $f(u)$ uniformly continuous?

Comment: Yes, because the domain would be compact, hence $u$ is uniformly continuous and one can prove that composition of uniformly continuous functions is also uniformly continuous

Comment: I hope this is not too stupid: But why is the domain compact in this case?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the notation, $u \in C([0,T], \mathbb R)$ doesn’t imply that $u:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb R$?

Comment: No, the notation means that $u\colon [0,T]\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $u$ is continuous.

Comment: I can’t answer right away, would have to give some thought

Comment: I'll ask this as a separate question.